# Bootstrap reset nested grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is an example of my issue: [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jzvbu2de/1/)

I have something like the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="big-box">image</div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want the inner `<div class="col-xs12">` to be the default size for the container. But the 'parent' div is taking over (as expected). How can I stop this without removing the parent?

In the JS Fiddle you can see what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following:

```
.col-sm-expand-2 {
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -10%;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzvbu2de/11/)